# irrigation setup for a newly planted 15 foot cherry tree and 15 foot river birch

Tags: trees, irrigation

I have a newly planted 15 foot cherry tree. I am setting up an irrigation system. How often and how much water should I give the tree? I also have a newly planted 15 foot river birch , same question.

Comment: full sun, part sun?  Type of soil: sand, clay? What part of the world do you live in?  Type of planting: bare root, balled and burlapped?